# ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal con este menú de navegación?

Tags: html, bootstrap, navbar

Tengo el siguiente menu.html dentro de la carpeta vistas y quiero que se incluya en cada pagina de mi proyecto.
Ya probé poniendo el menú en la carpeta raíz, en vistas, en html, en php, con require con include y no encuentro porqué me marca error, si por ejemplo, voy a una pagina si me manda pero si quiero dar clic a la misma pagina me marca error o si estoy en la pagina y quiero ir a otra me marca el navegador la ruta de un archivo junto con la otra y me marca error obviamente. Espero puedan orientarme en lo que estoy haciendo mal
Gracias

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>CRUD php y mysql b5</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- cdn icnonos-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Third navbar example">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample03" aria-controls="navbarsExample03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample03">
                <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Cuentas del activo</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="vistas/cuentas/activo/circulante/inicio.php">Circulante</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="vistas/cuentas/activo/fijo/inicio.php">Fijo</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diferido</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown02" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Cuentas del pasivo</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Circulante</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fijo</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diferido</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown03" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Movimientos del activo</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Circulante</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fijo</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diferido</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown04" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Movimientos del pasivo</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Circulante</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Fijo</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Diferido</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown05" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Reportes</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balanza de comprobación</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Balance general</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Estado de resultados</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link">Opciones</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Adjunto foto de la estructura de carpetas
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se entiende lo que te ocurre, no dices el error que te aparece. Así a ojímetro veo que los dropdown no te funcionan porque no has incluido el [javascript de bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle), y aparte de eso en este ejemplo tienes casi todos los href apuntando a la misma página:  `href=#" cuando imagino que quieres poner enlaces a otras paginas.

Comment: Tampoco me cuadra eso de llamar a las vistas directamente desde los href que si tienen enlaces en tu ejemplo.  Como este:  `href="vistas/cuentas/activo/circulante/inicio.php`... no se si sabes el concepto de vista, pero no es ese. Debes tener algun sistema que capture tus urls y las redirija al controlador adecuado, normalmente capturandolas en el .htaccess y reenviandolas a un index.php que las gestione y sepa a que controlador llamar, para que este mediante modelos y vistas, te acaben generando la salida.

Comment: La realidad es que estaba empezando ese menú y me causaba conflictos pero no metía nada de javascript. Soy novato y no se mucho de esto. ¿Me recomiendas leer sobre vistas y sobre JS? Gracias.

Comment: @CarlosSanchez lo mejor es que no solo digas que tienes un error, mejor dinos cuál es exactamente, puedes hacerlo al dar clic en [edit]